# Oracle End Of Month values for Date Range

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

Oracle has a [`last_day()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions077.htm) function:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(to_date('01/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY')) from dual;
```

Results:

```
31/01/2016
```

How can I get a list of the EndOfMonths in a Date Range to use in a WHERE Clause, currently I'm using a big string and it is not intuitive or future proof eg:

```
SELECT * FROM Balances
WHERE TheDate IN
('31/Jan/2016','29/Feb/2016', '31/Mar/2016','30/Apr/2016', '31/May/2016','30/Jun/2016', '31/Jul/2016','31/Aug/2016',
'30/Sep/2016', '31/Oct/2016','30/Nov/2016')
```

I'd prefer to use a function to plug in Start and End Dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to generate a last day of month range:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(add_months(to_date('01/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), level) )
from dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
```

Change 10 to # months you need.  This assumes "TheDate" is a proper oracle DATE type.  Wrap with to_char if needed to format as string.

With @JeremyThompsons Months_Between suggestion:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(add_months(to_date('01-01-1991','DD/MM/YYYY'), level) )
from dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
(SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN 
   (TO_DATE('02-02-1999','MM-DD-YYYY'),
    TO_DATE('01-01-1991','MM-DD-YYYY') ) "Months"
    FROM dual);
```

The final query with @mathguys function order suggestion:

```
SELECT * FROM Balances b
WHERE TheDate IN
(SELECT add_months(LAST_DAY(to_date('28/Feb/2015','DD-MM-YYYY')), level) 
from dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
(SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN 
   (TO_DATE('30/Nov/2016','DD-MM-YYYY'),
    TO_DATE('28/Feb/2015','DD-MM-YYYY') ) "Months"
    FROM dual));
```

And one more of @mathguys optimizations, no need for scalar subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM Balances b
WHERE TheDate IN
(SELECT add_months(LAST_DAY(to_date('28/Feb/2015','DD-MM-YYYY')),level)
from dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= MONTHS_BETWEEN 
   (TO_DATE('30/Nov/2016','DD-MM-YYYY'),
    TO_DATE('28/Feb/2015','DD-MM-YYYY')) );
```

Comment: So just a Months_Between to finish it off, I'll edit your answer, thanks

Comment: `add_months` can be used with the first argument a month-end, and in that case it returns only month-ends. Then you can save the calls to `last_day()`. Try for example `select add_months(last_day(sysdate), level) from dual connect by level <= 12;` and adapt as needed.

Comment: Further enhancement, the `LAST_DAY` can be eliminated if an end of month date is entered, why I mention this is because of @mathguy suggestion and its not immediately obvious that Oracle's `ADD_MONTHS` function is quite intelligent *and optimized under the hood*, you can use the 28th or 29th of Feb, the 30th Apr but not 30th of Mar. Great team work guys!

Comment: @JeremyThompson - `months_between()` can be used by itself in the CONNECT BY LEVEL condition, it does not require a scalar subquery surrounding it. It returns a number that can be used directly in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like the following which will return the end of months for all the months:

```
create or replace function getEndOfMonths return varchar2 as
    cnt number;
    current_year varchar2(5);
    end_of_months varchar2(180) := '';
    end_of_month varchar2(13);
begin
    select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') into current_year from dual;
    for cnt in 1..12 loop
        SELECT LAST_DAY(to_date('01/'||cnt||'/'||current_year,'DD/MM/YYYY')) into end_of_month from dual;
        end_of_months := end_of_months||','||end_of_month;
    end loop;
    return substr(end_of_months,2);
end;
/
```

**Update:**
Following is based on month range:

```
create or replace function getEndOfMonths(start_month number, end_month number) return varchar2 as
    cnt number;
    current_year varchar2(5);
    end_of_months varchar2(180) := '';
    end_of_month varchar2(13);
begin
    select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') into current_year from dual;
    for cnt in start_month..end_month loop
        SELECT LAST_DAY(to_date('01/'||cnt||'/'||current_year,'DD/MM/YYYY')) into end_of_month from dual;
        end_of_months := end_of_months||','||end_of_month;
    end loop;
    return substr(end_of_months,2);
end;
/
```

Comment: That is not going to work.  That is one big string, not an IN list.